# Microsoft Security Essentials is blocking my WordPress website in IE11

Tags: pages, security, virus

When I try to browse my WordPress website by using IE11, I get blocked by MS Security Essentials.  It works ok with Google Chrome.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a security issue? FTP to the site and detect the files, and maybe you should also look into the content of .htaccess

Comment: You site will have a virus/link to spam ware sites. Download all content and look through the files I would start but replacing the default Wordpress install files and then remove all themes your not using after this replace all the plugins you have with new copies from where you purchased or if from Wordpress reposetry. You will need to go to google and fill in a form for them to check your site is virus free then they will unblock. Most important before you do this change all passwords an check for rouge user accounts then install a security plugin as they will try to infect the site again.

Comment: Hacked sites are a very broad topic with no specific fix-all solutions. Start by reading the [hacked FAQ](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) in the Codex. When your hosting environment is clean or you've decided to try a fresh installation, check out the [Hardening WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) page for some precautions to take to help ensure that it doesn't happen again.